# Upgrade from .NET 6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13 to 6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5, app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles(); causes error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-6.0

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview - Version 16.11.0 Preview 1.0 . My web-app work very well with .NET 6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13 . This is my upgrade process demonstrate by git diff

```
donhuvy@DESKTOP-23PIH3M MINGW64 /d/github/acc (main)
$ git diff
diff --git a/Client/acc.Client.csproj b/Client/acc.Client.csproj
index dfa936b..b07ab26 100644
--- a/Client/acc.Client.csproj
+++ b/Client/acc.Client.csproj
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
+<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

   <PropertyGroup>
     <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
@@ -9,11 +9,11 @@


   <ItemGroup>
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" PrivateAssets="all" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.4" />
-    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.4" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" PrivateAssets="all" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7" />
+    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
diff --git a/Server/acc.Server.csproj b/Server/acc.Server.csproj
index 4361cae..d87d0a4 100644
--- a/Server/acc.Server.csproj
+++ b/Server/acc.Server.csproj
@@ -6,8 +6,8 @@
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
-    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Document.Processor" Version="21.1.2-beta" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
+    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Document.Processor" Version="21.1.3" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
@@ -16,12 +16,12 @@
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.2" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.2">
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.1" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.1">
       <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
       <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
     </PackageReference>
diff --git a/Shared/acc.Shared.csproj b/Shared/acc.Shared.csproj
index 70fad51..53ceae6 100644
--- a/Shared/acc.Shared.csproj
+++ b/Shared/acc.Shared.csproj
@@ -5,8 +5,8 @@
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
-    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Blazor" Version="21.1.2-beta" />
-    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="6.0.0-preview.3.21201.13" />
+    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Blazor" Version="21.1.3" />
+    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
     <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
   </ItemGroup>

(END)
```

[image]

Error

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.Use(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder, System.Func`3<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate,System.Threading.Tasks.Task>)'.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ComponentsWebAssemblyApplicationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<UseBlazorFrameworkFiles>b__1(IApplicationBuilder subBuilder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MapWhenExtensions.MapWhen(IApplicationBuilder app, Func`2 predicate, Action`1 configuration)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ComponentsWebAssemblyApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles(IApplicationBuilder builder, PathString pathPrefix)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ComponentsWebAssemblyApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
   at acc.Server.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in D:\github\acc\Server\Startup.cs:line 62
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

[image]

If I try comment this line,
[image]

File `Startup.cs`

```cs
using acc.Server.Data;
using acc.Server.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace acc.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "FilesHere")));
            // services.AddDevExpressBlazor();
            // https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/401608/common-concepts/troubleshooting#an-unhandled-exception-on-the-current-circuit
            services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[] { "vi-VN" };
            var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
                .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
                .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.Use()`  apparently does not exist in the update.

Comment: Do you guide a solution or a dirty way to fix it quickly?

Comment: Call a different method that actually exists?

Comment: Please guide me a concrete solution/few lines of code. I am not understand these things much.

Comment: Seems that you already filed a bug report at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33074.  I would wait and see what they have to say.

Comment: Make sure you do a clean build when upgrading.  The compiler doesn't always recognize the changes in Net Versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need delete `bin` , `obj` , re-build, and the most important part is running command:

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9
```

Thanks to the author who commented at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33074#issuecomment-849667061

See more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json?tabs=netcore3x#globaljson-and-the-net-cli (document for .NET 6 is not exist now)

Comment: `global.json` is only needed if you already have a `global.json` file either in the current or parent folders. Clearing the binary folders and rebuilding should be done every time you upgrade the SDK or publish. You may even have to do this when upgrading a NuGet package if it adds files that aren't deleted automatically

Comment: *Without* a `global.json`, dotnet will use the latest SDK and runtime. `global.json` is needed to force the use of older versions

Comment: Thank you for your information (have some helpful information). In my practices, I must run the above command to avoid error happen. I cannot run solution if I did not run the above command.

Comment: Which means you forgot an old `global.json` in one of the parent folders. If you use the same machine for experimentation and production development you must have a `global.json` on your work projects, to avoid targeting .NET Core 6 by mistake. Perhaps you put that file in the disk's root instead of the root of your work-related projects

Comment: I just create new Blazor WebAssembly project from latest preview stack, I really did not seen `global.json` . I searched it by Windows Exporer in all solution. https://i.imgur.com/zndLacK.png

Answer (score 0):

Check if there a package reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server in the .csproj file.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.1" />
```